# Add Cookie to Maintain font-size Across jQuery Mobile Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cookies

I'm trying to add a cookie request to this code to maintain the user's selected font-size across jQM pages once they change it. Never done this before. Can anybody get me started?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".increaseFont,.decreaseFont").click(function () {
        var type = $(this).val();
        var curFontSize = $('.gridContainer').css('font-size');
        if (type == 'increase') {
            $('.gridContainer').css('font-size', parseInt(curFontSize) + 2);
        } else {
            $('.gridContainer').css('font-size', parseInt(curFontSize) - 2);
        }

    });


});
</script>
```

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a cookie, why not use localStorage?  It never expires and is really easy to use within JavaScript. Use setItem to store the font size:

```
localStorage.setItem('FontSize', curFontSize);
```

Then to retrieve the font size on another page:

```
var curFontSize= localStorage["FontSize"];
```

If later you want to remove the saved font size:

```
localStorage.removeItem("FontSize");
```

Here is some documentation on localStorage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: That's actually an excellent idea. Trying to put it into practice -- where am I going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/jeremytripp/uxBLG/3/

My thought was that I'd have it check what the curFontSize is, then go through the change command, then set it again, but I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uxBLG/4/. After getting the value from local storage, you need to actually set the font size on the Data div.  Now increase font size, then click the run button again and see that the font size remains.

Comment: @ezanker would you know how I can do the same with local storage here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065527/save-addclass-with-jquery-cookie-or-local-storage Please :-)

Comment: @user2513846, I posted an answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

I woudl recommend jQuery.Cookie to work with Javascript and Cookies, otherwise it can be a mess...
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie