# Remember button click with page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a new web mobile with jquery mobile. When I move from `#page1` to `#page2` by clicking on a button (from 1-10) the button is set to black and when I click "back" from `#page2` the button in page one is not black any more. I actually want to remember when I click back on which button I've already clicked before.

One more thing. When I'm clicking on a button in page1 for example button 3, the button 3 in page 2 is active (black) and he shouldn't be active. I want it to be unactive.

my code:

```
<div dir="rtl" id="page" data-role="page">
    <div class="fiveButtons" style="margin-bottom:10px float:left "> 
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a10" data-p1="10" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;"  onclick="showFrontLayer5a(6)"> 6 </a> </div>  
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a9" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(7)"> 7 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a8" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(8)"> 8 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a7" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(9)"> 9 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a6" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(10)"> 10 </a></div> 
        </div>              
    <div data-role="content" class="gapdiv"></div>
    <div class="fiveButtons"  style="margin-bottom:10px float:left "> 
        <div class="b"><a class="c"  id="a5" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(1)"> 1 </a> </div>  
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a4" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(2)"> 2 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a3" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(3)"> 3 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a2" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(4)"> 4 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="a1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5a(5)"> 5 </a></div> 
    </div>    
</div>
<div dir="rtl" id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div class="fiveButtons" style="margin-bottom:10px float:left "> 
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b10" data-p1="10" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;"  onclick="showFrontLayer5a(6)"> 6 </a> </div>  
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b9" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(7)"> 7 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b8" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(8)"> 8 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b7" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(9)"> 9 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b6" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(10)"> 10 </a></div> 
    </div>              
    <div data-role="content" class="gapdiv"></div>
    <div class="fiveButtons"  style="margin-bottom:10px float:left "> 
        <div class="b"><a class="c"  id="b5" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(1)"> 1 </a> </div>  
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b4" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(2)"> 2 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b3" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(3)"> 3 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b2" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(4)"> 4 </a></div>
        <div class="b"><a class="c" id="b1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" style="margin: 1px;" onclick="showFrontLayer5b(5)"> 5 </a></div> 
    </div>     
</div>    
<script>
    function showFrontLayer5a(a) {
        q3b=a;
        var url="http://111.11.11.11/#page2";
        window.setTimeout(function(){window.open(url,'_self');
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);},500);
    }
</script>    
<style>
    .fiveButtons .c:active{
        color:#ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

please yuor advise,
Mor

Comment: Problem 2 is most likely because you are not using unique ids across the 2 pages. The buttons on page 2 should have different ids than those on page 1.

Comment: I tried to give every button other id but it's still not working I thought it's because the class=c . but I tried to create another class=d . and still not working. any other suggest?

Comment: As terrible as the hashbang (`#!`) is, you might want to consider using it to transfer data between pages. Alternatively, you could use params (`?=`). Then, at the top of each page, include a function that parses the data and changes the CSS accordingly.

Comment: @Mor, for more advice you will need to show us your code, or even better, create a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue. For storing which button was pressed, you can use localstorage, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204206/add-cookie-to-maintain-font-size-across-jquery-mobile-pages/20224823#20224823

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies to save the button that was clicked and set it to black when you go back by reading the cookie. The problem is, all css that jquery changes is reset when the page loads. To save it, use cookies.